# Lavarel assets use In resources?

Tags: laravel, directory, assets, laravel-mix

Is it better to keep asset (CSS, JS, images) documents in the public folder? Is there a correct way to keep it in the resources folder? How should I include it? Or is it right to keep it in resources? Is this a problem when I use a Laravel Mix?

Comment: If it's not private, then no issues at all.

Comment: What do you mean by private? How do I include one? Example: {{ resources_path(...) }} ???

Comment: Your source files live in the resources folder.  Your compiled assets should be placed in the public folder so that they are accessible by browsers.

Answer (score 0):

yes its better to keep images,css and js in public folder beacuse other folder and files may contain some senstive data as public path is accessible from url as well , so its better to to use ByDefault public folder for saving data like images and so on..But if you want to change the base url of public folder then u may change it by
**config/filesystem.php** and look for this code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKrgB.png)
and run **php artisan config:clear**